# How to determine line-height from % height of container?

Tags: html, css

In a classic layout (header fixed, main and footer fixed), i would like to center the text of the main element. For the purpose of this exercise, I would like to set the line-height such that it equals the height of the main element, then the text would be vertically centered. The absolutely positioned main element has top and bottom padding of 10%, so it's 80% high.

How can I get the line-height to equal the container height?

```css
*    { box-sizing: border-box; }
html {     height:       100%; }
body {     margin:          0; 
        font-size:       10px; }

header { border: 1px solid black;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 10%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

main { border: 1px solid black; left: 0; right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    /* height: 80%; */
    bottom: 10%;
    line-height: 80%;
}

footer { border: 1px solid black;
    position: fixed;
    height: 10%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
        <header>Header</header>
        <main><div>Main Div</div></main>
        <footer>Footer</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an old trick with a pseudo and the `div` set as an `inline-block` element and `vertical-align`. The pseudo is to be 100% of main's height, since it is an absolute element sized via coordonates, the pseudo should take `height:100%;`

Demo below

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
}

header {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 10%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

main {
  border: 1px solid black;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  /* height: 80%; */
  bottom: 10%;
}


/* centering trick */

main::before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
}

main:before,
main>div {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* end centering trick */

footer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: fixed;
  height: 10%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<main>
  <div>Main Div</div>
</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

**But this really not the way to do and this example is not going to teach you anything usefull, today you can easily relay on the flex or grid model to avoid tricky methods .....**

Forget about `line-height` for this kind of visual, this is not the job of line-height and not the way to use it. line-height:80%; means 80% of 1em (the font-size set ).

Comment: Totally right, line-height 80% is without sense. I was thinking it would be like line-height 80 (without units)

Comment: The best worse solution... :)

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case you can rely on `vh` unit

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
}

header {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 10vh;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

main {
  border: 1px solid black;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10vh;
  bottom: 10vh;
  line-height: 80vh;
}

footer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: fixed;
  height: 10vh;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<main>
  <div>Main Div</div>
</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this while still using line height to center your text would probably be to use view port units instead of %. Simply set your main section and it's line height to 80vh (or however tall you want it to be).

```
main {
  height: 80vh;
  line-height: 80vh;
}
```

If you aren't familiar with viewport units and how they work, [here is a quick explanation with some examples](https://www.sitepoint.com/css-viewport-units-quick-start/). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Are You Sure You Want to do it with Line Height? It might have certain consequences. See this Pen https://codepen.io/iamrgaurav/pen/xJMpWO
But as Stephen represented it is the way you want to achieve

```css
.footer{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
}
.header{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
}
.main{
  position:relative;
  top:10px;
  height:100%;
  line-height:90vh;
  background-color:#ddd;
}
```

```html
<header class = "header">header</header>
<main class = "main">
  <div>Main</div>
</main>
<div class = "footer">footer</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Setting the `line-height` won't make text vertically aligned. for horizontal alignment, use `text-align: center;` in the container.

For vertical alignment, you could use the following CSS since it;s absolutely positioned.

```
main div {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2dg4cq3z/2/)

Comment: Appreciate it, but please see question title. Its about figuring out what the value for line-height should be, when all i know is the height of the container in %